# How to fix garbled font issue

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my system 2 days ago. Today i am getting the fonts in some garbled manner only in gedit. Whats the reason and how to fix this issue?[image]

Comment: Mine does that sometimes, but I have no idea why. Restarting fixes it.

Comment: Same here, restarting would do . But i need to know why this happens VERY often..

Comment: If it's relevant, I'm using Intel builtin graphics on an Asus laptop. I think it's related to graphics.